# How to render something on Component B when a button is clicked on Component A which has no relation to each other?

Tags: svelte

**Header component**

```
<header>
    <li>hello board</li>
    <ul>
        <li>add a column</li>
        <li>manage tags</li>
        <li>settings</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Main component**

```
{#if "add a column" is clicked}
...
{/if}
```

Would like to point out that these components are independent of each other i.e, not a child or parent of each other. Thank you for your answers in advance :)

Comment: you can use stores for this https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to handle an `isColumnClicked` variable (which is a boolean) in the common parent of `Header` and `Main`.

So you will give as prop to `Header` a callback `onAddColumn` that will be triggered when you click on the list item:

*Header.svelte:*

```html
<script>
    export let onAddColumn;
</script>

<header>
    <li>hello board</li>
    <ul>
        <li on:click={onAddColumn}>add a column</li>
        <li>manage tags</li>
        <li>settings</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Then the `Main` component should get the value from `isColumnClicked` as a prop:

*Main.svelte:*

```html
<script>
    export let columnClicked;
</script>

{#if columnClicked}
  <p>Yuhu!</p>
{/if}
```

And the common parent (lets say `App`) will orchestrate the `isColumnClicked` update:

*App.svelte:*

```html
<script>
  import Header from "./Header.svelte";
  import Main from "./Main.svelte";

  let isColumnClicked = false;
</script>

<body>
  <Header 
    onAddColumn={() => {
      isColumnClicked = true
    }} 
  />
  <Main columnClicked={isColumnClicked}/>
</body>
```

See the working example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hofstadter-5uswl?file=/App.svelte).

---

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment it was more clear of what your intention was:

> Ideally, the "add a column" button on the header creates a column component on the board (main area) component

For this type of behaviour you will have to adopt another logic which feat more to a component architecture using a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store) like [@grohjy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2777805/grohjy) mentioned.

So all your components are going to be orchestrated by a common object that contains your data (so here a list with all your columns). Lets say for the example that it will have this structure:

```js
[
  {
    title: "column title",
    todos: [...a list of todos object]
  },
  ...
]
```

Next step is to initialise a store that handle this object. You can for example add to this store a `addColumn` function:

*board.js:*

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const emptyColumn = {
  title: "New Column",
  todos: []
};

function createBoardStore() {
  const { subscribe, set, update } = writable([]);

  return {
    subscribe,
    addColumn: () => {
      update((board) => [...board, emptyColumn]);
    },
    reset: () => {
      set([]);
    }
  };
}

export const board = createBoardStore();
```

Then your `Main` component just map all the existing `column` using the store:

*Main.svelte:*

```html
<script>
  import { board } from "./stores/board.js";

  let boardValue;

  const unsubscribe = board.subscribe(value => {
    boardValue = value;
  });
</script>

{#each boardValue as column}
  <li>{column.title}</li>
{/each}
```

And so your `Header` just need to call the `addColumn` function since the `Main` component is reactive to the store:

*Header.svelte:*

```html
<script>
    import { board } from "./stores/board.js";
</script>

<header>
    <li>hello board</li>
    <ul>
        <li on:click={board.addColumn}>add a column</li>
        <li>manage tags</li>
        <li>settings</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Like this you have a clean front-end app that only rely on data and not on tons of events. Here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cache-djcwl?file=/App.svelte).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Althought I must say that this feels rather unintuitive, dont you think? Is there any other way to do this because I dont see why we should pass props to the app.svelte then back to where its rendered. Is there a way we a component can directly pass an event to another component without passing props between correlating components?

Comment: @rohanharikr you can use `createEventDispatcher` to dispatch event from component to parent, but it itself doesn’t bubble through multiple components. You can also use `setContext` and `getContext`, but the best way to go is I believe to use `store` as mentioned in other comment.

Comment: Js custom events also seem to bubble through multiple components. Here is an example: https://svelte.dev/repl/a52b9bdb308547caaacff73e7e8d2958?version=3.24.1

Comment: @rohanharikr Yep sure this method isn't appropriate for creating apps ;) But this is because the logic that you want to implement isn't the best too. I guess that you want to do kind of a local routing system where if you click on `add a column` you go to the AddColumn section and so on am I right?

Comment: Sorry but no. My project is like a trello clone app. Ideally, the "add a column" button on the header creates a column component on the board (main area) component. Just want to emphasise again that if the header component was used in the board component, it would have been straightforward but in this, its not the case because there is no need for a header component to be in the board component. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @rohanharikr I updated my answer with a better logic implementation :)

Comment: @johannchopin This is awesome, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for!